Redirecting to HTTPS while keeping the specified port number
I am using IIS 10.0.17763 and configured HSTS to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. It works fine going from port 80 to 443, but if is specify a different port it still redirects to 443 instead of the original port.
I entered HTTP://site.mydomain.com:8080 and expected it to go to HTTPS://site.mydomain.com:8080. Instead, it went to HTTPS://site.mydomain.com without the port number.
Is there a way to do this with HSTS alone or do I need to use IIS URL Rewrite rules?

Thats not how HTTP/HTTPS works. You always need two ports. One for HTTP, one for HTTPS. You cant send plain HTTP request to a HTTPS Server or vice versa.

Then is it possible to specify the corresponding HTTPS port number in the redirect using HSTS? The site uses multiple port numbers to specify which database to use. I am guessing I will need to use rewrite rules, which I have not used.

The RFC document actually forbids any mapping from port 80 to non-443 port,
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-8.3

if the URI contains an explicit port component of "80", then
the UA MUST convert the port component to be "443", or
if the URI contains an explicit port component that is not
equal to "80", the port component value MUST be preserved;
otherwise,

So you don't have a choice but to use port 443.
In case you have multiple sites on port 443 and limited IP addresses, enable SNI (as modern web servers all natively support that).
Please only use standard ports and have both HSTS and URL rewrite rules in place. Those ensure best experience to your end users.

Since HSTS will not do what I need I will try using rewrite rules.  Thanks.
